# Guava Caches / configurable eviction / buffer replacement strategies

Tags: java, guava

Are other replacement strategies planned regarding the maximum size eviction? I would need an MRU algorithm, such that the system benefits from the cache. The system stores records in blocks on disk or in cached pages in-memory, whereas the pages/records are not clustered (that is probably not stored in preorder after updates). The records in my case are nodes in a tree-structure.

The system assigns record-IDs in ascending order (that is at first they are in preorder) and also stores the records in pages with an incremented ID (0, 1, 2...). After updates however, if the records/nodes for instance need to be traversed in preorder it might be that a page is read with records 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10... but nodes have been inserted between node 6 and 7 (for instance node 11 with a large subtree). In this case the cache is only useful if it preserves the first page (which stores records 1,2...,10 if the cache size is 1 and the subtree rooted at node 11 belongs to another page. Then the first page must be fetched twice. It's similarly the case for other tree-traversal methods, that MRU is more useful than LRU, but maybe other clever algorithms exist which might be even better suited. Would probably be an aspect of self-tuning.

Sorry for the long description of my use case (a versioned data storage system), but I hope it's a valid use case. Thus it would be nice if the size-based eviction would be configurable as in some cases probably also LRU perfectly makes sense (however probably not for tree-traversals).

Edit: I probably don't even need concurrency support as long as I'm only allowing one write-transaction at a time (because Guava splits the entries into different segments, such that it's not using a global LRU algorithm).

Answer (score 3):

The design philosophy was to not make a guarantee on the algorithm behavior of which element the size based eviction policy decides to evict. This provides flexibility to evolve to a more advanced eviction policy, such as [LIRS](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/hpcs/WWW/HTML/publications/abs02-6.html), and improve the cache's design, e.g. not be segmented. The contract is that the cache will try to intelligently choose a victim that satisfies the majority of use-cases.

The current implementation is already overly complex, imho, and I would not be in favor of providing numerous toggles that tune the algorithm. That would make the api confusing for a small subset of users, restrict the ability to make design improvements, and increase the complexity beyond a tolerable level. Its preferable to roll your own solution that best matches your problem when Guava's generalist approaches are not the correct fit.

The right answer depends on your use-case. If you don't need high concurrency then there are many obvious answers. If you do, though, then forking [ConcurrentLinkedHashMap](https://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap) to use an MRU policy may be the least painful. A middle ground of a custom implementation, e.g. perhaps using a simplified version of the buffering strategy, may be the easiest to encapsulate in a large code base.

Comment: I'm currently not even sure if it's a good idea. It might as well be that pages 1, 2, 3 and 4 are read in order (whereas the maximum size of the cache/buffer is 3). Then fetching page 4 evicts page 3, but it might have to be read a second time, as a subtree has been inserted between nodes on page 3 (and the subtree is located on page 4). Thus, a preorder traversal will have to read 1,2,3 and 4 and then 3 again, thus LRU would be better ;-) Kind of a dilemma, I guess. Clustering such nodes would be best, but then again only for exactly one access pattern (pre-, post-, level-, in-order...).

Comment: It sounds like you want a scan resident policy like LIRS.

Comment: Thanks, then I will certainly stick with Guava Caches, as I'm using the library extensively. Hopefully LIRS will be implemented in the future :-) Or... I think (well, now know that ;-)) Charles Fry already implemented a LirsMap.